# Html/CSS Hidden Horizontal Overflow

Tags: html, css

I have used **overflow-x:hidden** to hide my horizontal scroll bar. Its working well but I'm not able to see my horizontal scroll bar, but still it exposes the overflow when I select-and-drag towards the right side.

I need to avoid this. Can some body help me out in fixing it?

```
html
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Try setting a width on your `html` element. Something like `width: 100%`

Comment: even if i give width:100% Still its moving towards right side can you suggest some other way to prevent it please!

Comment: Try setting the same on the `body` tag. You just need to play around with this a bit.

Comment: Oh, remove `position: absolute` on your `html` element. That should never be necessary

Comment: Mat. i tired giving it to body and removed position:absolute still its same nothing changed but if i used overflow:hidden it works but i cant able to use vertical scroll bar i need only vertical scroll bar to work not horizontal Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change `overflow-x:hidden` to `overflow:hiddden`

https://jsfiddle.net/L6tde8x8/

Comment: Thank you godmode..it works but i cant able to use vertical scroll bar i need only vertical scroll bar to work not horizontal Thanks!!

Comment: if you break this section into it's own div and set `overflow:hidden`, it shouldn't break the parent scrolling